# derivative of the inverse function of $f=\sqrt{2x+3}$

Tags: calculus, inverse

Note that $g'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(g(x))}$, where $g=f^{-1}$.

- If $f(x)=x^3+2x-1$, find $g'(2)$.

Here is how my professor did it:

We notice that $f(1)=2$, so $g(2)=1$. Then

$g'(2)=\frac{1}{f'(g(2))}=\frac{1}{f'(1)}=\frac{1}{5}$.

However, they then proceed to do another problem differently.

- If $f(x)=\sqrt{2x+3}$, find $g'(x)$ at $x=2$.

They did it this way:

$f(2)=\sqrt{7}$, so $g(\sqrt{7})=2$. Then

$g'(\sqrt{7})=\frac{1}{f'(g(\sqrt{7}))}=\frac{1}{f'(2)}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(2)+3}}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}}=\sqrt{7}$.

Following the first method, shouldn't this be:

$f(x)=2 \iff \sqrt{2x+3}=2 \iff x=\frac{1}{2}$

$g'(2)=\frac{1}{f'(g(2))}=\frac{1}{f'(\frac{1}{2})}=...$.

Comment: The question is poorly phrased IMHO. You are correct if they write $g^{\prime}(2)$ like they did in the first question. However, I think that they wanted you to find the value of $f^{\prime}(2)$ instead.

Comment: To me, what you have done is correct. They computed the value of $g'(x)$ at $x=\sqrt{7}$ and not at $x=2$.

Comment: what you've done is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement of the second problem is somewhat confusing as both $f$ and $g'$ are written in terms of the variable $x$, and then it is specified that $x=2$.  However the most reasonable interpretation is
$$\hbox{if $f(x)=\sqrt{2x+3}$, find $g'(2)$}\ .$$
Assuming this is what is meant, the solution is wrong and your correction is right.

Because of this possibility of confusion, IMHO the best way to solve this kind of problem is to use two different variables.  I would write it this way: let $y=f(x)$.  Then $x=g(y)$ and so we want $\frac{dx}{dy}$ when $y=2$.  We have
$$y=2\ \Leftrightarrow\ f(x)=2\ \Leftrightarrow\ \sqrt{2x+3}=2\ \Leftrightarrow\ 
  x=\frac12$$
and so
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=1\Big/\frac{dy}{dx}=1\Big/\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x+3}}=2\ .$$
In fact in this case, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is very closely related to $y$,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac1y\ ,$$
so you can take a short cut,
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=1\Big/\frac{dy}{dx}=y=2\ .$$

Comment: @ David: could you precise what do you mean by "very closely related to y" ?

Comment: @upax $1/y$ as already stated in answer.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse function $f^{-1}$(x) = $\frac{x^2-3}{2}$, and the derivative of that is just $x$.